# homology of face links of a triangulated manifold

Tags: manifolds, homology-cohomology, triangulation

In a triangulation of a general topological space, we can define a [face link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_simplicial_complex) (for any face in the triangulation). Intuitively, this is a kind of "$\epsilon-$sphere" in metric space.

In chapter 3.8 of Stanley's *enumerative combinatorics* is stated that for any nonempty face of a triangulation of manifold (with or w/o boundary) it is well-known that the homology group of the link of this face should be the same as a sphere or ball.

Well, at least now, I can't find a little hint to prove this, and unfortunately, Stanley's book did not suggest any reference to this result.

Is there anyone who gives a comment to this result? Any little one would be appreciated.

Comment: This appears to be Theorem 5.2.4 in Anant R. Shastri's *Basic Algebraic Topology*. (This is based on browsing the book on Google Books, not on perusing an actual copy).